# Error while installing pyGCO, shows pybind11 warnings

Tags: python

I am trying to install pyGCO: [GitHub](https://github.com/Borda/pyGCO) , but it shows me this error:

`WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pybind11: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\marcu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pybind11-2.6.1.dist-info\\METADATA'`

As I see it's pybind11 error, so I tried to install it using `pip install pybind11`, but it gave me the same error: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\marcu\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\pybind11-2.6.1.dist-info\\METADATA'`.

I tried to clone the source code and install from there, but it didn't work too. How should I install pyGCO?